# How to insert key value pairs into a HTTP GET request sent manually through a socket

Tags: sockets, http, get

I manually create a HTTP GET request and send it through a socket to the server. This works reasonably well but I would like to add key/value pairs(or query string) to the request(e.g., `compact=1&event=started` in the example below). I am not sure where exactly to insert them in the request.

```
# Code in Python 2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urlparse import urlparse
import socket

# Create HTTP GET request
def make_request(parsedURL):    
    h = ""
    if (parsedURL.path == ""):
        h += "GET / HTTP/1.1\n"
    else:
        h += "GET " + parsedURL.path + " HTTP/1.1\n"
    h += "User-Agent: myhttpclient\n"
    h += "Host: " + parsedURL.hostname + "\n"
    h += "Content-Type: text/plain\n"
    h += "Content-Type: utf-8\n"
    h += "Accept-Encoding: gzip\n"
    h += "Connection: Keep-Alive\n\n"
    return h

# Create a socket connection and send the HTTP GET request
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parsed = urlparse('http://bt.careland.com.cn:6969/announce?compact=1&event=started')
    address = parsed.hostname
    if (parsed.port == None):
        port = 80
    else:
        port =  parsed.port
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        s.connect((address,port))
    except Exception as e:
        print "Can't connect to socket."

    httpRequest = make_request(parsed)       # calls the function to create GET request
    s.sendall(httpRequest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add them to the request line, ie:

```
GET /announce?compact=1&event=started HTTP/1.1
```